# Shared area of $2$ circles (polar integral)

Tags: calculus, self-learning

Given $x^2+y^2=4y$ and $x^2+y^2=4x$ find the shared area  of the 2 circles

What I tried was :

so first I transformed them to polar coordinates
I got $r=4cos\theta$ for $x^2+y^2=4x$ and $r=4sin\theta$ for $x^2+y^2=4y$

After that I did $4cos\theta=4sin\theta$ then $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ I am not sure but according to this I believe that $\frac{\pi}{4}≤\theta≤\frac{\pi}{2}$ lastly I did the integral

$\int_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{2}((4cos\theta)^2-(4sin\theta)^2) d\theta $
after integrating I got $-4$ which is a wrong answer.

what am I doing wrong? thanks for any help and tips!
Edit: I forgot to mention that I havent studied double integrals yet , I learned polar system and this formula $\int_\alpha^\beta\frac{1}{2}(r(\theta))^2 d\theta $

Comment: Have you tried a diagram? Can you see how your integrand's sign varies?

Comment: You need not to integrate to find the area.

Comment: @user I mean sure, but the point of the exercise seems to be to use the tools they've learned in a section to practice setting up and doing problems leading up to more complicated examples like cardioids

Comment: @J.G. I did draw the circles .. I still cannot see what I am missing can you give me a hint?

Comment: @NinadMunshi exactly , according to the book I should use integrals here for practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Please note that for $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$, you are bound by circle $4 \sin\theta $ and for $\frac{\pi}{4} \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, you are bound by circle $4 \cos\theta$.

So the area is given by,  $A =  \displaystyle 2 \int_0^{\pi/4} \int_0^{4\sin\theta} r \ dr \ d\theta$

or $ \ \displaystyle 2 \int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{1}{2}(4\sin\theta)^2 \ d\theta$

You can see that the area between $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$ and between $\frac{\pi}{4} \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ are same. So we multiply by $2$ or use the fact that $\sin\theta = \cos (\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta)$.

Comment: thank you for the help , but my mistake I forgot to mention I cannot use double integrals as I haven't gotten there yet. what I learned so far is polar system and this formula $\int_\alpha^\beta\frac{1}{2}(r(\theta))^2 d\theta $

Comment: OK see my edit.